# How retrieve data below another data inside reyclerview in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a shop app where people can post comments about a product and other people can answer below the first comment.

I want to retrieve the comment and its replies into one `Recyclerview` like Instagram does, as shown in the following image. But I don't know where to start can you help me thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have a RecyclerView for all the comments. Each comment item would have a layout containing the comment content and a RecyclerView for its replies.

So, for example, your data could be a list of Comment objects with each one having a list of Reply objects inside it.